# What could be causing a skip in object_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake

After inadvertently overwriting my development database of ~100 rows/table with my fixtures test data (just 2 rows/table), the next new object created in each model started at id = 897600.

What could have caused this? Does this mean I created 897500 test objects that are somehow not visible in my database? Not sure if this is something I should be concerned with, but any feedback would be appreciated.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 with Rails 3.2

Please let me know what additional information would be useful in clarifying my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails fixtures use hashes of fixture keys in order to determine record `id`s. This allows all the [good stuff](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/10/26/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-fixtures-just-got-a-whole-lot-easier) (some old article from around the time this feature was introduced). In order for your tests to run, records which get created in test examples need not to clash with these hash ids, so `ActiveRecord` resets PK sequences to `max(id)+1` for each table which it touches with fixtures. Here's how your PKs can get up to numbers like `897600`.

Comment: Thanks @Serge. So I understand then that this is expected behavior in the test database. I guess this is not an issue in the test db because the id is not visually referenced?

Comment: So, the only way to reset the id numbers in my development database is to start over with rake db:reset?

Comment: It's not an issue in test db, because hashes are consistent. Another run of test suite wouldn't lead to 2X bump of ids. As for development, yes `db:reset` is the simplest path. The hard way is: manually clean fixtures, then issue `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(table_name)` on each table.